# How do the $labels.instance get resolved in Prometheus Alets rules?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, monitoring, prometheus-alertmanager, substrate

Here is a sample "rules.yml" file used to monitor a node (Substrate node on Ubuntu 22.04) using Prometheus:

```
groups:
  - name: alert_rules
    rules:
      - alert: InstanceDown
        expr: up == 0
        for: 5m
        labels:
          severity: critical
        annotations:
          summary: "Instance $labels.instance down"
          description: "[{{ $labels.instance }}] of job [{{ $labels.job }}] has been down for more than 1 minute."

      - alert: HostHighCpuLoad
        expr: 100 - (avg by(instance)(rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[2m])) * 100) > 80
        for: 0m
        labels:
          severity: warning
        annotations:
          summary: Host high CPU load (instance bLd Kusama)
          description: "CPU load is > 80%\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS: {{ $labels }}"
```

I can't figure out how the variable $labels.instance is resolved. Where do I set this? Apparently, the generated alerts put out literal "$lables.instance" instead of the a value representing the instance name.

I went through the prometheus config file and not sure where to set that value. Anyone could point me in the right direction be a great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with

> Apparently, the generated alerts put out literal "$lables.instance" instead of the a value representing the instance name.

lies in this line:

```
          summary: "Instance $labels.instance down"
```

For value to be properly substituted it should be in format {{ $labels.instance }}

> I can't figure out how the variable $labels.instance is resolved.

annotations are generated using labels and value of time series which triggered firing of alert (in this case `up`).

Comment: Do you know how I can see all the available labels that I can use under $labels ?

I tried making an API call to /api/v1/lables and got a list, but when I user for example {{ $labels.application }} it does not get resolved.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! It makes sense now. I can see these labels beforehand when running the expression on /graph Prometheus port 9090